# (PTK) Start failed when creating tool instance: Console

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

When I load up PTK, I get the following error:

```
start failed when creating tool instance: Console
```

Do you know what the problem is?

I am running the standard python 2.7.5 from python.org.

I installed wxPython(3.0) as required.

PTK never worked (I just installed it today)

My log file looks like this:

```
12/01/14 15:39:01 - ptk_lib.app                                      - INFO     - Starting      MessageBus
12/01/14 15:39:01 - ptk_lib.message_bus.message_bus                  - INFO     - Registered node : App
12/01/14 15:39:01 - ptk_lib.app                                      - INFO     - Starting Toolmanager
12/01/14 15:39:01 - ptk_lib.tool_manager.toolmanager                 - INFO     - Toolmanager started
12/01/14 15:39:01 - ptk_lib.app                                      - INFO     - Starting core tools
12/01/14 15:39:01 - ptk_lib.core_tools.taskicon.taskicon             - INFO     - Initialising tool
12/01/14 15:39:01 - ptk_lib.message_bus.message_bus                  - INFO     - Registered node : TaskIcon
12/01/14 15:39:01 - ptk_lib.core_tools.taskicon.taskicon             - INFO     - Tool initialised
12/01/14 15:39:01 - ptk_lib.core_tools.fileio.fileio                 - INFO     - Initialising tool
12/01/14 15:39:01 - ptk_lib.message_bus.message_bus                  - INFO     - Registered node : FileIO
12/01/14 15:39:01 - ptk_lib.core_tools.fileio.fileio                 - INFO     - Done Initialising tool
12/01/14 15:39:01 - ptk_lib.core_tools.console.console_tool          - INFO     - Initialising tool
12/01/14 15:39:01 - ptk_lib.message_bus.message_bus                  - INFO     - Registered node : Console
12/01/14 15:39:01 - ptk_lib.tool_manager.toolmanager                 - ERROR    - start failed when creating tool instance: Console
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ptk_lib\tool_manager\toolmanager.py", line 106, in start_tool
    self._loaded_tools[name]=tool()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ptk_lib\core_tools\console\console_tool.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.frame = ConsoleFrame(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ptk_lib\core_tools\console\console_frame.py", line 137, in __init__
    self.book.Bind(aui.EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_RIGHT_DOWN,self.OnTabRight)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_RIGHT_DOWN'
```

Comment: Which version of wxPython did you install?

Comment: I installed wxPython 3.0

Comment: Looks like it's recommended at wx 2.8+, so I would try wx2.8 or at most 2.9. wxPython 3.0 only came out this month...

Comment: Thanks for the info Mike. I found out that in the newer wxPython,  EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_RIGHT_DOWN is now EVT__AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_RIGHT_DOWN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the info Mike Driscoll. I found out that in the newer wxPython (3.0), `EVT_AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_RIGHT_DOWN` is now `EVT__AUINOTEBOOK_TAB_RIGHT_DOWN` . I went to the site-packages folder,

Python27\lib\site-packages\ptk_lib\core_tools\console\console_frame.py and changed the needed lines to match.